# QuickBooks: How to add "line numbers" to invoices/quotes/etc ?

Tags: quickbooks

I just want to number the lines.  1,2,3,4,5 etc.  I am not seeing how to do it.  QuickBooks 2013 Pro

Thanks,
Bryan

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I just stumbled upon this. QuickBooks Pro cannot autonumber lines of an invoice or other forms. However, you can do that with a QuickBooks add-on like FormCalc SST. There's an example of [numbering lines on a Packing Slip](http://www.goflagship.com/products/sstprobsolv.htm) on the FormCalc SST web site.